# How to make KDE applications look native in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, themes, qt, ambiance

Qt apps look out of place on my desktop. They use a different theme and color palate to the native GTK apps.

Is there a way to get KDE/Qt5-based apps to integrate better by using the same theme as the GTK apps. If not, how can I set the theme of Qt5 apps on my gnome-based desktop?

Answer (score 4):

You can install the qt5-style-plugins package from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt install qt5-style-plugins
```

Then edit ~/.profile with a text editor. For example, using Gedit, you can open that file from a terminal using:

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

In this file, add the following as a new line, without removing anything from the ~/.profile file:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2
```

Next, save the file and finally logout and log in. This will make Qt5 apps use Gtk2 style, which will look better, but not perfect.

For more styles, you can try [qt5ct](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qt5ct/) (a PPA is [available](https://launchpad.net/~mati75/+archive/ubuntu/qt5ct)).

For Qt5 applications you can also use [Kvantum](https://github.com/tsujan/Kvantum), which allows using a SVG-based theme engine. It comes with built-in themes that resemble some popular Gtk themes, like Ambiance, Yaru (Communitheme), Adapta, Adwaita, and more, which makes Qt apps look a lot better. The application also allows various customizations, assign themes to specific applications, and more. For how to install Kvantum in Ubuntu, see [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/05/use-custom-themes-for-qt-applications.html) page.